# How to VOID an Authorized transaction through paypal form

Tags: php, paypal

I am using paypal form to authorize payment on my website using its hidden variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="authorization" >
```

How can I void this authorized transactions via my website (in case if user cancel his order).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the [DoVoid API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/dovoid-api-operation-nvp) call to be able to perform this from your website.